# Why am I getting invalid column name error in group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to make this request. I added the group by because I had duplicates. I am getting the error:

> Invalid column name for the columns in the group by.

I have read a lot of posts regarding this type of error but I am still stuck. Also I would like to know if I should use `sum()`. Help please.

```
INSERT INTO tabA
       ([load_number]
        ,[load_date]
        ,[no_command]
        ,[no_document]
        ,[id_transc]
        ,[division_cd]
        ,[activity_cd]
        ,[project_cd])
 
select 1 [load_number]
      ,getdate() [load_date]
      ,'' [no_command]
      ,'' [no_document]
      ,coalesce(c.id_numb,-1) [id_transc]
      ,coalesce(b.elem_cd,-1) [division_cd]
      ,coalesce(d.budget_cd,-1) [activity_cd]
      ,'' [project_cd]

from tabB b

   left join tabC c on c.credit = b.account
   left join tabD d on d.activity = SUBSTRING([b.name],CHARINDEX('-',[b.name])+1,LEN([b.name])) and d.transc = '1010'


    group by [load_number]
            ,[load_date]
            ,[no_command]
            ,[no_document]
            ,[id_transc]
            ,[division_cd]
            ,[activity_cd]
            ,[project_cd]
```

Comment: You just need to include the syntax (that defined the column) in the GROUP BY - not the alias that you've given it.  eg. GROUP BY coalesce(c.id_numb,-1), rather than GROUP BY [id_transc]

Comment: Please include sample data and expected results.

Comment: Little trick to save you redefining columns in `select` and `group by`: place it in a `cross apply(values` and group and select that instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about duplicates, you can just use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct 1 [load_number],
       getdate() [load_date],
       '' [no_command],
       '' [no_document],
       coalesce(c.id_numb,-1) [id_transc],
       coalesce(b.elem_cd,-1) [division_cd],
       coalesce(d.budget_cd,-1) [activity_cd],
       '' [project_cd]
from tabB b left join
     tabC c
     on c.credit = b.account left join
     tabD d
     on d.activity = SUBSTRING([b.name],CHARINDEX('-',[b.name])+1,LEN([b.name])) and d.transc = '1010';
```

You can't use column aliases defined in the `select` in the `group by` in SQL Server.

Comment: I want to avoid duplicates because it generates the violation of unique key constraint error. Using the distinct doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @kst92 . . . If fixed the problem you have described in this question, which is invalid column names in the `group by`.  If you have a different question, you should ask a *new* question with a clear description, sample data, and desired results.